# Exporting R data - column classed as data.frame exports as blank with write_xlsx

Tags: r, dataframe, export, xlsx

I am new to R, I looked for other solutions such as converting the datatype or exporting as csv (which generated weird formatting) and was unable to find a solution. I think I am overlooking something simple - thank you in advance!

I exported my dataframe (dfCCVul) to excel via write_xlsx.  The data exported fine, except for the column "logPopDens.PopDensity" which is a column I had created by taking the log of another column (PopDensity)  That column exports blank.

This is a snippet of the data :

```
PerPoverty  PerNotWhit  PerServWor  logPopDens.PopDensity
13.1        42.5        12.92       6.288305
30.2        48.9        13.03       4.861129
10.1        17.1        9.16        4.819233
26.3        49.8        23.32       4.862599
16.6        42.8        20.24       5.02263
12.5        25.6        8.28        4.448282
15.3        20.3        5.89        5.048188
```

When I check the data type of the new column, the results look embedded:

```
 $ logPopDens:'data.frame': 1315 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ PopDensity: num  3.52 3.07 2.64 1.16 2.27 ...
```

When I check the class, the output is:

```
> class(dfCCVul$logPopDens)
[1] "data.frame"
```

My thought was to convert the datatype, but I've received a series of errors after trying different syntax, for example:

```
> data$logPopDens <- as.numeric(as.character(data$logPopDens))
Error in data$col11 : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable 

> data$logPopDens.PopDensity <- as.numeric(as.character(data$logPopDens.PopDensity))
Error in data$logPopDens.PopDensity : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Is there another way to export the values of the logPopDens?

Thank you!

Comment: It will help if you [make this problem reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a sample of the complete data frame `dfCCVul` (all relevant columns) and showing all code that generated new columns. Is the new column name `logPopDens.PopDensity` or `logPopDens` ? You use both.

Comment: Please show how you ran `log`. Also, include all `library` lines with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dfCCVul$logPopDens` is a dataframe, convert it into a vector. One way would be with `unlist`.

```
dfCCVul$logPopDens <- unlist(dfCCVul$logPopDens)
```

Or I think this should work as well.

```
dfCCVul$logPopDens <- dfCCVul$logPopDens$PopDensity
```